# Merge plots and imported images

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, import

I am trying to plot some things using Mathematica. I haven't used Mathematica for plotting before
, so apologies if my question is basic.

I have the following image, which is my *target* image:
[image]

I also two more plots that I did using Mathematica, and that I plotted in *separate* files. They are in log-log scales. So let's say image 1 is in file 1, and image 2 is in file 2.
For example, image 1 is given by

[image: The target image]

Image 2 is

[image]

I can export and import both images and load them to different files.

My goal, however, is to **merge** the plots that I did in Mathematica with the *target* image, i.e. I want to add image 1 and 2 to the target image such that it also appears as a colored area there. Is something like that possible?

If not:
Can I at least merge my image 1 and 2 in a *single* picture and plot it next to my target image?

Comment: To combine the two Mathematica plots, see [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html). To include the image, see [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html), which you can then put into the [`Prolog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Prolog.html). So in total, you would have `Show[plot1,plot2,Prolog->Inset[image,...]]`

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks, but 'Show' does apparently not work with imported images. Is there an alternative? The point is that plot1 is already imported (i.e. its a jpg file)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - you need to use `Inset` for the images, and `Show` for the plots created by Mathematica, as I have tried to hint at in my last comment. To use your naming scheme: `Show[image1,image2,Prolog->Inset[target,...]]`.